# If point is nothing how come line which made up of set of points has length

Tags: math, geometry

As per  [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)) , In particular, the geometric points do not have any length, area, volume, or any other dimensional attribute.But when line is made up of set of points how come it has length?
I am not too good in maths but this question was back in my mind since many days. Someone please clear things up. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basic math, not programming. (Programming tends to use pixels)

Comment: This should be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is a great question, which really goes to the heart of an important topic in mathematics. A short answer is that any countable set (even an infinite countable set) has measure zero, but an uncountably infinite set can have measure greater than zero. My advice is to take this question to math.stackexchange.com and see what they say there.

Answer (score 0):

A line is made up of at least 2 points AND the space between them. Add another point and the space between the last point and this next point lengthens the line.

Comment: Mathematically a line has an infinite length. You describe a line _segment_.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  in mathematics, there is a concept of "[Lebesgue Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)". This assigns values to length, area, volume, etc. by manipulating the interval `[0,1]`.

Here's an intituitive explanation. A point at `x` can be represented as a limiting case of the interval `[x,x+h]` as `h` approaches `0`. The measure of the point, `(x+h) - x = h` as `h` approaches `0` is therefore `0`.

However, if we take a line segment--say, `[0,1]`--and decompose it into `n` intervals `I[k]` with `k` being over the integers from `0` to `n-1`, each will take the form `I[k] = [k/n, k/n + 1/n)]`. If we let `n` go to infinity, each of the `I[k]` can be modeled as a point because `1/n` is approaching `0`. If we take the measure of each point, we get `1/n` as `n` approaches infinity, or zero. On the other hand, if we sum the measures of the points, we get `1/n * n = 1`, the measure of `[0,1]`.